# How to splat a hash table to write-output for debugging?

Tags: powershell

Using powershell, I'd like to print the result of splatting a hash table. This is an example I came up with (but the `Write-Output` doesn't work as I expect):

```
$SomePath = "C:\test\path"

$params = @{
    p = "$SomePath"
    r = "Foo"
    a = "Bar"
}

$destinationDir = ''

if (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($destinationDir)) {
    $params['b'] = $destinationDir
}

Write-Output "Params: @params"
```

The result of `Write-Output` is literally:

> Params: @params

Is there a way I can print the expansion of this command for debugging purposes? I'd also like to eventually store the expanded invocation to invoke later from a variable, like so (I assume it would work):

```
$cmd = "MyProgram.exe @params"
& "$cmd"
```

But if that's a whole new can of worms, I'm happy enough with getting just `Write-Output` to work in my initial example.

Here is my powershell version:

```
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Patch  PreReleaseLabel BuildLabel
-----  -----  -----  --------------- ----------
7      0      3
```

Comment: You can't - the result of _splatting_ a hashtable depends on the parameter set it's bound to.

Comment: Oops, used the wrong word didn't I? I fixed it. Do you have a link that explains the "depends on the parameter set its bound to" part? I'm still learning this and haven't seen that explained anywhere. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to observe the effect splatting has on a Win32 PE in your current shell, I would suggest using `Add-Type` to compile a simple debugging utility:

```bsh
$sourceCode = @'
using System;
using System.Management;
using System.Diagnostics;
public class Program
{
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT CommandLine FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = " + Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id))
    using (ManagementObjectCollection procs = searcher.Get())
    {
      foreach (ManagementBaseObject process in procs)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(process["CommandLine"].ToString());
      }
    }
  }
}
'@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $sourceCode -OutputType ConsoleApplication -OutputAssembly ~\printCmdline.exe
```

The resulting executable will print the command line arguments of its own process - exactly what we need to see.

---

Now that we have an executable to test against, let's see what happens:

```bsh
$SomePath = "C:\test\path"

$params = @{
    p = "$SomePath"
    r = "Foo"
    a = "Bar"
}

~\printCmdline.exe @params
```

Which should print something like:

```
"C:\Users\void.pointer\printCmdline.exe" -r:Foo -p:C:\test\path -a:Bar
```

Answer (score 2):

Note: **[Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting) only works reliably with *PowerShell* commands**, because the way PowerShell translates it for external programs, as shown in [Mathias' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64598105/45375), is not a format that most external programs understand.

As Mathias points out in a comment on the question, **you cannot directly get a splatting invocation's equivalent expressed as individual arguments**.
However, **you can use the [`Trace-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Trace-Command) cmdlet to *trace* parameter binding**, *IF* you have a command (represented by `$yourCommand` below) that actually accepts the parameters specified in the hashtable:

```
Trace-Command -pshost -name ParameterBinding { & $yourCommand @params }
```

Note: `Trace-Command`'s output is verbose and technical; interpreting it takes some practice.

---

**Your desire to capture the equivalent of a splatting-based invocation in a command-line *string* is impossible to achieve in *all* cases**, given the object-based nature of PowerShell: **not all objects can be represented faithfully as *strings***.

That said, **if you know that the arguments being passed are limited to *strings*, *numbers*, and *switches***, you can do the following:

```
# Sample hashtable used for splatting, limited to strings, numbers, switches.
$somePath = 'C:\test\path'
$params = [ordered] @{
    Path = "$SomePath" # string
    Count = 42         # number
    Skip = $True       # [switch] parameter, expressed as a [bool] value in splatting
}

# Translate the hashtable into an equivalent command-line string.
$params.GetEnumerator().ForEach({
  $val = $_.Value
  if ($val -is [string]) { $val = "'{0}'" -f $val.Replace("'", "''") }
  '-{0}:{1}' -f $_.Key, $val
}) -join ' '
```

The above yields a string with the following content:

```
-Path:'C:\test\path' -Count:42 -Skip:True
```

---

*Prepending the command name* to the string resulting from the above would give you a string representation of a complete command.

That string representation could be saved to a script file, for instance.

**If you wanted to execute the string containing the command-line *directly*, you'd have to resort to [`Invoke-Expression`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/)**, because `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-), does *not* operate on entire command lines, only on the *names/paths* of commands specified via a variable, quoted string, or expression.

**The obligatory warning about `Invoke-Expression`**:

`Invoke-Expression` should generally be *avoided* and used only as a *last resort*, due to its inherent security risks. In short: Avoid it, if possible, given that superior alternatives are usually available. If there truly is no alternative, **only ever use it on input you either provided yourself or fully trust** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375).

***In general*, if possible, use PowerShell's own, fully object-aware way of defining snippets of code to be executed on demand *later*, namely [*script blocks*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`).**